# Only allowing the logged in user to submit a comment on a post

Tags: django

I am having trouble getting the author of the comment when the form submits

This works fine for my post method, not so much for commenting on the post

**Models.py**

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)#title of a post
        content = models.TextField()
        date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #if a user is deleted all of their post will be as well
        view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('forum.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Views.py**

```
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']

    def for_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.users
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        vc = self.object.view_count
        self.object.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
        self.object.save()
        self.object.view_count = vc + 1
        return data
```

**Post_detail template**

```
{% extends "forum/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ object.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted }}</small>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ object.view_count }}</small>
          {% if object.author == user %}
            <div>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
        {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
          <div class="comment">
            <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
              <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
              <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
            </div>
            {% empty %}
            <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
            {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

The error I am getting is "NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_comment.author_id". Im not sure what is different from my post CreateView

Comment: Can we see the other view?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser yes

Comment: There's a typo in the name of your function. It should be `def form_valid(self, form)`, you have a missing `'m'` . Also `users` shouldn't be plural, change it to `self.request.user`

Comment: You have a typo at 'def for_valid'. I guess this is causing the author not being set when you save the form as a model instance.

Comment: @JordanM. After fixing the two typos. The new error is "NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_comment.post_id" which is very similar to the original.

Comment: @karp0 that means you also need to assign a `Post` instance to the `Comment`, just like you did with `author` in the `form_valid` method.

Comment: @JordanM. I'm sorry I'm a little confused as I am new to django.

Comment: That means that there is no post assigned, meanwhile `null = True` so the site can work, then migrate

Comment: @Moha369 Add it where?

Comment: In post field in `Comment` model

Comment: To fix your error you should assign the current post in `form_valid` function

Comment: For this to work properly you need to create a `PostDetailView`, override the `get_context_data` and pass a `CommentForm` with an initial data for the `post` field. Inside the template of the `PostDetailView` the form tag of the comment should be pointing to the `CommentCreate` view

Comment: @JordanM. edited post with PostDetailView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `ModelForm` for `Comment` in a `forms.py` file inside your app:

```py
# your_app/forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['post', 'text']
        widgets = {
            'post': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Write your comment here...'}),
        }
```

After that edit your `PostDetail` view so you can pass the `CommentModelForm` with the `post` instance already set in the form:

```py
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        vc = self.object.view_count
        self.object.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
        self.object.save()
        self.object.view_count = vc + 1
        initial_comment_data = {
            'post': self.object,
        }
        data['comment_form'] = CommentModelForm(initial=initial_comment_data)
        return data
```

Add the `CommentModelForm` to you `CommentCreate` view:

```py
class CommentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentModelForm

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And finally, the template of your `PostDetail` should look like this:

```html
# your_app/templates/your_app/post_detail.html

...
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'yourapp:comment-create' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ comment_form }}
  <button type="submit">Place a comment</button>
</form>
<div>
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <p>{{ comment.text }} - by {{ comment.author }} at {{ comment.created_date }}</p>
  {% empty %}
    <p>No comments yet. Be the first one!</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: im not sure what I am supposed to put in for the URL of the form post.

Comment: You should put the name of the url for CommentCreate, like `{% url 'create_comment' %}`

Comment: I am now getting the error: Reverse for 'add_comment_to_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment/$']

Comment: Edit the url of your `CreateComment` and remove the pk from it, so it would take no arguments

Comment: edit out the pk and went to post a comment. Error is now:NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_comment.post_id. This is the same error as before.

Comment: Did you forget to add the initial data for the `CommentModelForm` in the `PostDetail` view?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I made a correction in the `initial_comment_data`. Please take a look

Comment: I fixed it in my program, I still have the same error

Comment: Please try removing the `fields` attribute in the `CommentCreate` view

Comment: A new error:Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CommentCreate) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.

Comment: I added the `CommentCreate` to my answer, this should fix it

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try **self.request.user** instead of **self.request.users**. And also change **for_valid** to **form_valid**. If that doesn't work try something like this. **new_comment** is the **instance** that you can save here and return from the function instead of the **form**.

Inside the **form_valid** function of **CommentCreate** class

```
     new_post = form.save(commit=False)
     new_post.author = self.request.user
     new_post.save()
     return new_post
```

Inside the **form_valid** function of **PostCreate** class :

```
     new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
     new_comment.author = self.request.user
     new_comment.post = super().form_valid(form)         
     new_comment.save()
     return new_comment
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have two typos**

`for_valid` should be `form_valid`

```
def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.users
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and `self.request.users` should be `self.request.user`

Comment: I have fixed the two typos. I now have an error: "NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_comment.post_id" which is very similar to the first error

Comment: Are you assigning the Post instance to the comment somewhere? That functionality is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm extremely new to Django, sorry.

Comment: I don't see any code which links the comment to the post.

Comment: How is the comment supposed to know which post it is attached to?

Comment: The comment would be in the post_detail which is an HTML file.

Comment: But when do you assign a value to `comment.post`?

Comment: No, you need to get the specific post the comment is attached to and assign it in form_valid.

Comment: Is there a function to do that?

Comment: Can you pass the specific post ID to the comments?

Comment: You mean using the post_id as the foreign key?

Comment: You would use the post_id to get the ForeignKey for comment.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do what your saying.

Comment: Can I see your template? We can probably make a get which can pass the data to create comment.

Comment: Yes one second.